# add a new std class to object of arrays in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following class / object of array using var_dump ;

```
$all_stores = array (size=4)
        0 => 
        object(stdClass)[29]
          public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
          public 'store_name' => string 'asdasd' (length=6)
          public 'desc' => string ' sdasdasd' (length=9)
          public 'profile' => 
            object(stdClass)[32]
              public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
              public 'fname' => string 'asdas' (length=6)
              public 'lname' => string 'asd' (length=6)
              public 'gender' => null
              public 'zipcode' => string '63011' (length=5)
```

and another std class

```
$media =
    object(stdClass)[34]
      public 'id' => string '16' (length=2)
      public 'title' => null
   (length=37)
      public 'type' => string 'store_image' (length=11)
      public 'profile_id' => string '1' (length=1)
```

What i really want is to merge this two class keep them as std / Objects.
I need to add each memeber of the media class as key or varible like `profile` in `$all_stores` variable.

### expected output is as follow

```
0 => 
        object(stdClass)[29]
          public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
          public 'store_name' => string 'asdasd' (length=6)
          public 'desc' => string ' sdasdasd' (length=9)
          public 'profile' => 
            object(stdClass)[32]
              public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
              public 'fname' => string 'asd' (length=6)
              public 'lname' => string 'asd' (length=6)
              public 'gender' => null
              public 'zipcode' => string '63011' (length=5)
          public 'media' => 
            object(stdClass)[34]
             public 'id' => string '16' (length=2)
             public 'title' => null
         
          public 'zipcode' => string '63011' (length=5)
```

Thankyou

Comment: Can you please try to rephrase your question?

Comment: please also add the desired output to the question.

Comment: Let's say you have an object called $object. Are you trying to append the media std class to $object so that you can do something like $object->media or $object->medias?

Comment: hey guys it  reprased and out put expected is as give

Comment: yes cro i want to access media object added to that former parent varible object of arrays please

Comment: The best way is what @Cro mentioned. If you just simple merge them, the `id` property (and the same named properties) will be overwritten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get your media however you need to. I'm going to make an example:

```
$medias = $this->media_model->getMyMedia();
```

After that all you have to do is set it like this:

```
$all_stores->medias = $medias;
```

Or since your $all_stores is an array:

```
$all_stores[0]->medias = $medias;
```

---

### Edited

```
    $all_stores= $this->with('xxx')->get_all();

     //get all medias file associated with the stores


 foreach ($all_stores as $key => $value) {
    $all_stores[$key]->media = $this->media->get_by('store_id',$value->id);
   }
        var_dump($all_stores);exit;
```

Comment: brillaint idea lets try it